# Porting qt based qml app to windows store app

Tags: c++, qt, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, windows-store

I have a qt 5.2 x64 based qml app almost completely written using native std c++ and additionally, I have some win32 API code in it(just 2 files).

So, I researched a bit and found out that Windows store apps have a new Windows Runtime API(WinRT) and the qt code can be recompiled using winrt port of qt. Also, the win32 api code has to be rewritten using WinRT API.

1. So, previously I had vs2013 x64 libraries of qt with which I compiled my application. Now, while migrating to windows store app what are the things that I should do?
2. I only see x86 winrt libraries available on qt download website. Where are the x64 ports?

**Edit:** Seems like x86 winrt libs are actually x64 itself.

Please let me know if you need more info. Any help would be invaluable.

Comment: Most of the Qt-Code will work the same on winrt. Just change the kit and try to compile it! Of course, the native win32 parts will fail to compile, and a few features (for example `QProcess`) are not available when using winrt.

Comment: @Felix: The majority of the Win32 API is supported in UWP Windows Store Apps. There is no requirement to rewrite everything using the Windows Runtime alternatives. I don't know why you believe that Win32 code would fail to compile. See [Win32 and COM for UWP apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt592904.aspx) for a complete list of Win32 and COM APIs available.

Comment: @SRINI794 Have you find the solution. I am also in similar situation, I have created the application in Qt creator, now I need to submit on Windows app store.

Comment: @Haris Sorry I could not find a solution for this.

Comment: @SRINI794 Thanks for the feedback.  Just before I found youtube link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1pTeysNkRkk seems a solution for my problem, working with it now.